# integral calculus problem

Tags: calculus, integration

So I am using wolfram alpha in my integration. If I integrate expressions with ln, the answer of wolfram alpha is with log. Is it correct? Is it accepted in calculus?

Comment: Yes it it correct. Base $10$ log is just not useful for higher mathematics. So $ln=log$ in wolfram and many other sources

Comment: Yes. In anglo-american countries $\ln(x)=\log(x)$ But there are countries, like Germany where $\log(x)$ usually means that the base is $10$. It´s all about definitions.

Comment: Btw, wolfram alpha says how $\log(x)$ interpreted: "$\log(x)$ is the natural logarithm". And it provides an alternative: "Use the base 10 logarithm instead"

Comment: Also, WolframAlpha uses a complex logarithm by default. So, you won't see absolute values in the argument of the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm function is defined as the map $\log:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ by $$\log(x)=\int_1^x\ \left(\frac1t\right)\ \mathsf d t. $$
For any base $b>0$ and $a>0$ we have the equation $\log_b(a)=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(b)}$. This is known as the change of basis formula. Not that $\log b$ is a constant and so $\log b\log_b(a) = \log a$, so $\log_b(a)$ differs from $\log a$ by a constant. So in some sense, it does not matter what base logarithm we use. It is convenient to use the base $e$ as then e.g. $e^{\log x} = x$.

Comment: Also, $   b \ne 1  $.

Comment: @g.kov That is implied from $1^x=1$ for all $x\ne 0$, so $b=1$ cannot be a suitable choice of base of logarithm.

Comment: That's is exactly the point, why you state "For any base $b>0$"?